# How to prevent "Authentication Required" box from coming up?

Tags: java, .htaccess, authentication

I have a Java applet that is being included on a page in a directory that is password protected through a .htaccess file. When browses to pages in this directory I naturally have to authenticate at the beginning of a new session, but the problem is that this Java "Authentication Required" box is popping up on every page load.

I thought that maybe putting the applet outside of the password protected directory might fix the problem, but no joy.

Any idea what can be done to prevent the "Authentication Required" box from coming up?

Thank you!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-16.html

Comment: The Java plugin attempts to load the applet JAR but it doesn't necessarily use the same certificate store as the browser.

Comment: Does this question not help you at all? Maybe some Java console output would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995436/applet-loading-authentication

Comment: Does the authentication box still pop up every time on the page without the applet? What do the server logs say?

Comment: I think it has to do with the page loading in context that involves a required authentication. As a work-around, you could just put the username/password into the URL string. I think the format is: http://username:password@host:port/path/morepath

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that none of the applet's/html/page resources are coming from the secure folders, some of it is coming that is why you are getting the request or it is a blanket configuration.

Comment: @Nate Do you have to be compatible with every version of every browser out there or can you recommend one specifically?  Does your application/webpage run on a local machine or is it available online?  There are partial workarounds for your problem depending on these answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much as I'd like the bounty, I believe this question is a duplicate (of [Applet displays login dialog if basic authentication used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395413/applet-displays-login-dialog-if-basic-authentication-used)). I also believe that there's currently no workaround other than taking the jar file out of the htaccess-protected area of the web site.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a .htpasswd file, and setting up java to authenticate with that?

I could possibly provide a sample if you expand your question, including source code and possibly a directory tree.